# Leveraging the document/file create functionality

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api

Looking for some help to leverage the document/file create functionality for a chrome app that I had in mind. I tried looking at the SDK pages but couldn't find much there or maybe I was looking in the wrong place. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this sample Chrome Extension for accessing the Drive API. It handles some issues for you like OAuth 2.0, which could prove a bit tricky.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/gdocs